# How to terminate a WebSocket connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to terminate a websocket connection from server without closing the entire server? If it is then, how can I achieve it?

Note: I'm using NodeJS as back-end and 'ws' websocket module.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: browser refresh wont solve your problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to kick ALL clients without closing the server you can do this:

```
for(const client of wss.clients)
{
  client.close();
}
```

you can also filter `wss.clients` too if you want to look for one in particular. If you want to kick a client as part of the connection logic (i.e. it sends bad data etc), you can do this:

```
let WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
let wss = new WebSocketServer ({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.send('something');
    ws.close(); // <- this closes the connection from the server
});
```

and with a basic client

```
"use strict";
const WebSocket = require("ws");
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log("opened");
};
ws.onmessage = (m) => {
    console.log(m.data);
};
ws.onclose = () => {
    console.log("closed");
};
```

you'll get:

```
d:/example/node client
opened
something
closed
```

Comment: What about `wss` itself, doesn't one need to remove event listeners for example?

Answer (score 86):

So because of some sort of omission in the documentation regarding `ws.close()` and `ws.terminate()` I think the solutions in provided answers won't close the sockets gracefully in some cases, thus keeping them hanging in the Event Loop.

Compare the next two methods of `ws` package:

- `ws.close()`:

Initializes close handshake, sending close frame to the peer and awaiting to receive close frame from the peer, after that sending FIN packet in attempt to perform a clean socket close. When answer received, the socket is destroyed. However, there is a `closeTimeout` that will destroy socket only as a worst case scenario, and it potentially could keep socket for additional 30 seconds, preventing the graceful exit with your custom timeout:

```
// ws/lib/WebSocket.js:21
const closeTimeout = 30 * 1000; // Allow 30 seconds to terminate the connection cleanly.
```

- `ws.terminate()`:

Forcibly destroys the socket without closing frames or fin packets exchange, and does it instantly, without any timeout.

### Hard shutdown

Considering all of the above, the "hard landing" scenario would be as follows:

```
wss.clients.forEach((socket) => {
  // Soft close
  socket.close();

  process.nextTick(() => {
    if ([socket.OPEN, socket.CLOSING].includes(socket.readyState)) {
      // Socket still hangs, hard close
      socket.terminate();
    }
  });
});
```

### Soft shutdown

You can give your clients some time to respond, if you could allow yourself to wait for a while (but not 30 seconds):

```
// First sweep, soft close
wss.clients.forEach((socket) => {
  socket.close();
});

setTimeout(() => {
  // Second sweep, hard close
  // for everyone who's left
  wss.clients.forEach((socket) => {
    if ([socket.OPEN, socket.CLOSING].includes(socket.readyState)) {
      socket.terminate();
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```

---

**Important:** proper execution of `close()` method will emit `1000` close code for `close` event, while `terminate()` will signal abnormal close with `1006` ([MDN WebSocket Close event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent)).

Comment: This answer is better than the selected answer i felt!

Comment: Why do I find this explanation here but not in the documentation?

Comment: This answer is incredibly useful and insightful. Solved a major Websocket connection issue for me.

Comment: When you say "...keeping them hanging in the Event Loop" do you mean the client event loop or the server's event loop?

Comment: @sam, the Event Loop bound to the Node.js instance that is running the WebSocket server.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [ws documentation](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md), you need to call `websocket.close()` to terminate a connection.

```
let server = new WebSocketServer(options);
server.on('connection', ws => {
  ws.close(); //terminate this connection
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `ws.close()` in this way.

```
var socketServer = new WebSocketServer();
socketServer.on('connection', function (ws) {
  ws.close(); //Close connecton for connected client ws
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `var client = net.createConnection()` to create the socket you can use `client.destroy()` to destroy it.

With `ws` it should be:

```
var server = new WebSocketServer();
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // Do something and then
  socket.close(); //quit this connection
});
```