# WebSocket: call close() won't trigger onclose handler?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am reading Andrew Lombardi's book "WebSocket",
it said that

> You can manually trigger calling the onclose event by exe‐
>   cuting the close() method on a WebSocket object,

page 15

but when I call close() method, it didn't trigger onclose event...

**on Chrome:**
when call `close()`, server stop sending frames, and after a few seconds `(6-7 seconds maybe)`, my `onclose` handler was invoked.

**on iOS 11:**
when call `close()`, server stop sending frames, but onclose handler never invoked.

So, what's the truth of websocket close event?

**my demo app code in React**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      log: [],
    }
    this.ws = null
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this._open}>
          open
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this._close}>
          close
        </button>

        <div
          style={{
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#ddd'
          }}
        >
          {this.state.log.map((item, index) => {
            return <div key={index}>{item}</div>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  _open = () => {
    this.ws = new WebSocket('wss://cmb.100jc.net/answer/ws')
    this.ws.onopen = () => {
      alert('open')
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          log: prevState.log.concat('open')
        }
      })
    }
    this.ws.onclose = () => {
      alert('close')
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          log: prevState.log.concat('close')
        }
      })
    }
    this.ws.onerror = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          log: prevState.log.concat('error')
        }
      })
    }
  }

  _close = () => {
    this.ws.close()
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Found a solution?

Comment: Dang, no @BadhanGanesh

Answer (score 1):

the close() method attempts to perform graceful shutdown of the websocket. It waits `closeTimeout` seconds (default is 30 seconds) before actually shutting down the socket, during which the other peer can sand a close frame. After this period, the socket closes and the event is emitted. You can read more on this in [this great stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074052/how-to-terminate-a-websocket-connection).