# why does nodejs websocket server hang after closing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a websocket server that receives a message and then **closes**. From there, the script should behave as if the websocket server never existed...

I can't seem to figure why the websocket server keeps hanging.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 })

wss.on('connection', ws => {
    ws.on('message', message => {
        console.log(`Received message => ${message}`);
        ws.send('Hello! Message From Server!!');
    });

    ws.on("close", ws => {
        console.log("closed!");
        ws.close();
        //ws.terminate();
    });
});
```

**Both `ws.close` and `ws.terminate` leave the script hanging after the message is received.** How do I truly close the server and let the script act is if the websocket server never existed? I want to process the information I received from the client.

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49791634/5527786) suggests how to close the server but it doesn't work. Not even `process.exit` stops it!

**Edit**: It looks like I was supposed to do `wss.close()`. How can I now process the message that I received from the websocket server? I'm assuming I need to return a promise that I resolve somewhere?

Comment: Does ws.disconnect() work?

Comment: Is it ok to exit the whole app in your case? Or the app should still be running after the websocket server is closed?

Comment: the script must still be running because I want to process the data in the same script. Would a child process work?

Comment: Yes it will. But if the issue is not solved and the traffic is high, the server could potentially crash.

Comment: Is this the only part of code that's using websocket? If yes, then perhaps give socket.io a try?

Comment: It looks like I was supposed to also do `wss.close()`. Now, how can I process this data? I'm assuming I need to use some kind of promise?

Comment: But it's closed then it's closed. Does it supports more actions?