# how to close a websocket like if chrome window was closing to flush the buffer to 0

Tags: javascript, networking, websocket, tcp, network-programming

when with portfowarding the websocket pass by internet and only send when the connexion is close  (on my network it's like that), I first try to close the websocket by closing chrome(it worked), so now i found terminate that i think can do the same than closing the webbrowser,but it's only for the serveur that have this function and

the problem is that the buffer with close is not 0 but 13...

***so how can i do a `hard close`  with `ws.terminate` or something else to flush the buffer to 0 and a basic code like the one under without having the error?***

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://adress:5677/"),
messages = document.createElement('ul');
ws.onopen = function (event) {
            alert("connect");
            var lol = document.getElementById('lolz').value;
              alert(lol);
            ws.send(lol+" <p>\b\n\r");
            ws.close();
            console.log(ws.readyState);
         
            
            
            if(ws.readyState ==2){
                alert("ws.terminate");
                
                return ws.terminate();
               
        
       
            }
}
```

if you look the picture and the code you can see that i use`ws.close` but it doesn't seems to do something the buffer is not to zero and it's still connected this is a pictures of what is the status of the Websocket after ws.close(), i think that ws.close() waits that the serveur also close the connection and when the serveur waits to receive something before closing the serveur, it put's an error.

my pthon serveur if never

```
async def Time(websocket, path):
    
    
    try:
        a=await websocket.recv()
        print("final receive:"+str(a)+"/")
        a=str(a).split("<p>")
        a=a[0]
        print("/"+str(a)+"/")
    except:
        print("erreur")
    finally:
        socketout(bytes(a.encode("utf-8")))
        print("loop stop")
        loop.stop()
        print("loop ad stop")
        
start_server = websockets.serve(Time, "", 5678)
loop3=asyncio.get_event_loop()   

loop3.run_until_complete(start_server)
```

***a visual explication***
Thanks for helping
[![visual][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: because `WebSocket` object doesn't have any `terminate` method.

The `close` method (which you are calling) is enough to close the websocket. Where did you read about `terminate` method?

Since in your question you are speaking about "hard close" and in you code you are doing this check `ws.readyState == 2` I think you are looking for something to have `ws.readyState == 3`.

To have this is just matter of waiting a while after you called the `close` method.

The `onclose` property could help you; try adding following lines at the end of your script

```
ws.onclose = function(event) {
  console.log("Socket hard closed", ws.readyState);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i heard about websocket.terminate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074052/how-to-terminate-a-websocket-connection the problem is that after ws.close() on the nework page of the webbrowser coding tool it doesn't put a time only pending, ws.close wait that the serveur also close the communication to put 3 (with ws readystate) and when the serveur receive nothing he never close it

Comment: In that case, probably it's a server problem; anyway after `close` the communication is interrupted, which is the problem?

Comment: I don t think it s the serveur i had the problem with socket and websocket when the serveur send something to the client but in thise cas doing an hard close worked and it suceded to send something.How can i have after close a time and not pending? What is the terminate in the link that i gave you?

Comment: I need a fonction that close the socket without having a state closing like if you close the webbrowser

Comment: The `.terminate()` method is in [ws package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) but it is a server side implementation that doesn't works on browser (see first lines of readme). Anyway, I have clear **what** you want, but I have not clear **why** you want it. If it is just matter of wasted result, from an engineering point of view, the time you spent on this question costs much more than all resources wasted by a `CLOSING WebSocket`. ;)

Comment: when the websocket use portfowarding this mean that it's through internet but my box(rooter livebox play orange) only let pass the data when the connextion is close also like you can see on the picture after close the time is still pending, this mean if i'm correct that the connection is not close? it's not that i want absolutely that the connexion is close because i am maniacal but more for a technical problem that force me to do it if i want that the web page work, normally for a local connexion in the network close is enought but not in this case.Do you know how to do with network websocket

Comment: I don't know what "rooter livebox play orange" is and I have to admit I have not clear the senario... at least now it's clear why how may efforts :)
Since I think the short answer to your question is simply "you can't do it", if you try to explain better the problem in your question you could have better chances to find a solution.

Comment: you can't do a websock that pass by internet

Comment: i don't think that only my rooter have this security. I put the serveur code if never it help you

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so strong with python. And sorry I still have not clear the scenario. You said "rooter only let pass the data when the connextion is close" when usually it's the opposite - "you can't do a websock that pass by internet" while usully websocket pass through internet... it seems you are speaking about problems at connection time while the question is about connection closure. Sorry, probably it's due to my poor english...

Comment: and my poor english too

Comment: i had time to do a picture that can may help you. Thanks for leting  our time

Comment: Do you mean that when you have ws in CLOSING status you can't initiate a ne HTTP request?

Comment: no, the client can connect to the serveur but can't send. send=data=red, connexion=blue

Comment: And all data is flushed once the connection is closed?

Comment: yes, completly close like if the computer turn off internet in the middle of the process(after sending of caurse) or close chrome or microsoft edge

Comment: So it seems you have troubles upgrading the connection to websocket. My suggestion is to download a proven working websocket example (both client and server) and try it. If it works, you have to work on your server, if it doesn't, simply give up with websocket. Not last, if you need to close the connection to makes data arrive to the server you're actually not using the power of websockets.

Comment: thanks i thought that maybe if it was your code you now better how it works

Comment: i found one on youtube but my code is good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lv0oEnQY1pM it's seems that you need to do some things if you want that the data pass by internet. I have look and seen that the buffer is to 13after ws.close(); . can it be that, that cause the error? how can i flush it?

Comment: You can't flush it, there's no way (because there's no reason) to flush a websocket. I suggested to download a proven working SW to check if the problem is your network infrastructure. If you are 100% sure your SW should work, than the problem is your network infrastructure. If your network infrastructure doesn't allow websockets I'm sorry, but I'm afraid you have to give up.

Comment: i don't think it's that because i succed with websocket and python and portfowarding to do a code that when the client connect the serveur send to the client a data. i succed by doing a hard close after sending on the python side(the serveur)

Comment: Sorry if my words seem to be rude, but... if you **need** to hard close the websocket to let data arrive to the server, means that websocked **doesn't work as expected**. Dot. Once said that I can't say if the problem is in your code or in your network architecture. Trying to argue where is the problem is not a scientific way to proceed. Have you tried your server code on a public cloud machine to prove it works? Have you tried a proved working sw on your network architecture to prove it let websocket working? You need to prove where the problem is, otherwise you are wasting your time.

Comment: if it's the network how can you explain that all work when after sending i close chrome

Comment: :D that's crystal clear! instead, how can I explain you that having the requirement to close crome means it doesn't work as expected? :)

Comment: and that when i close socket because it doesn't wait that the serveur also close it works fin with my network

Comment: if the serveur can receive one time  by doing this, this mean that when i do this action i need to replace it by a line of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216284/discussion-between-daniele-ricci-and-websocket-learner).

Answer (score 2):

The `terminate` method you are trying to use is from a **server** implementation of WebSocket (not browser).

If you feel worried about the `close` method not actually closing the connection, you can verify it by yourself.

In your browser's console, type `let socket = new WebSocket("wss://javascript.info/article/websocket/demo/hello");`

Now in a Shell, type `ping javascript.info` which will give you the remote IPv6: `2606:4700:20::681a:c11`.

Now type `netstat -an -p tcpv6` which should display something like:

[image: Shell]

Finally, type `socket.close();` in the browser's console and run `netstat -an -p tcpv6` again, you'll notice that the previous row has disappeared.

Also, you'll notice that the row still shows in the browser's Network tab:

[image: Network tab]

So just don't rely on it when making assumptions on the socket's status.

Comment: so you say that the connextion is close but why don't the serveur see it , and i had a problem with socket where the serveur only could see the answer of the sending data from the client when the client close properlly the connexion. I understand nothing why it doesn't work?

Comment: I've answered your question about how to close a WebSocket on client side, now I'm sorry but I can't help you diagnose the whole network chain to the target server. Your connection is probably half-closed because of some intermediate network equipment https://superuser.com/questions/298919/what-is-tcp-half-open-connection-and-tcp-half-closed-connection

Comment: how can i pass from half close to close this is my question, i want a reall close connexion like if we close the client program `so how can i do a hard close with ws.terminate and a basic code like the one under without having the error?` this is the question in the post

Comment: You can't do a "harder" close than `ws.close()` since you can't control intermediate network equipments with JavaScript. If for some reason, an equipment drops TCP packets, the `FIN` message won't reach the server which will result in a half-closed connection

Comment: If you want to solve this problem, I suggest you use some network analysis tool like Wireshark in order to monitor the actual messages that are sent and received by the client and the server. Also, your question mentions JavaScript but your problem is not related to JavaScript at all, you already do everything you need to do with JavaScript.

Comment: ok, but why when i close chrome it work and their is no code that simulate this action. When chrome close it does a hard close so it work

Comment: hie do you know if javascript/info/article/websocket/demo/hello waits for data?

Comment: Yes sure, you can try this demo https://plnkr.co/edit/RZ6LnVnoFdIFVTBt try to replace John by your own name and the server will answer accordingly. That will help you diagnose where your problem is

Comment: it worked so i wonder if it can be cause because i use ws and not wss

Comment: why there is no port?

Comment: `wss` uses 443 by default and `ws` uses 80 just like `http`

Comment: I don't know you can look here https://javascript.info/websocket

Comment: with whiteshark what do i do with it?

Comment: Capture the network frames on the client machine and on the server machines. This will let you know if TCP packets are dropped or not and diagnose other communication problems if any