# Why does my network wait until the socket or websocket connection is closed before passing the data

Tags: python, sockets, networking, websocket

I have a router that is a livebox play(orange) like every router I think but the problem is that I need to have a connection completely closed before a socket/websocket server receives something.  For exemple in a websocket I need to close Chrome before the server receives.

I ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304332/how-to-close-a-websocket-like-if-chrome-window-was-closing-to-flush-the-buffer-t) about how to do a hard close in websocket and they tell me that my network is strange so when no one ask it, i ask my question ***why a router let pass the data only after having a completely closed connection***?

the python websocket serveur

```
async def Time(websocket, path):
   a=await websocket.recv()
   print(a)
   await websocket.close()
   
    
start_server = websockets.serve(Time, "0.0.0.0", 5677)
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()   

loop.run_until_complete(start_server)


loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Are you sure the issue isn't on the websocket server side? How it is implemented? You can additionally try websocket.org/echo.html for more testing.

Comment: when with the site the problem isn't resolve is either the rooter or the serveur so i put you  the serveur code in python. when it doesn't work with two libaries and two code i think that it's the rooter that blocked. Can it be because i didn't put the serveur in DMZ

Comment: @kmaork i hope that the serveur code will help you and answer our question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in python. But I see problem in async function, that waits till websocket connection closes to print message. Just remove `await websocket.close();`

```
async def Time(websocket, path):
   a=await websocket.recv()
   print(a)
    
start_server = websockets.serve(Time, "0.0.0.0", 5677)
loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()   

loop.run_until_complete(start_server)


loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: when it waits at the line await websocket.recv() it doesn't make a difference. Sorry and thanks for helping

Comment: I was talking about `websocket.close()`. Have you checked out this code?

Comment: it didn't help because in both case it doesn't execute the line `await websocket.close()` because he waits at the line `await websocket.recv()` and put an error because it puts an error

Comment: I tried to reply on `> why a router let pass the data only after having a completely closed connection?`. It is because async function is waiting till connection close, to print data. There were nothing about error in question. Can you add it into description, what error and when it happens?

Comment: the error comes from that after a time await pass and i have an error of `a` is not define because he received nothing.

Comment: do you know how can i use sub protocol with the python serveur